# How do I Auto-Label Hyperref Fillable Forms \TextField?

Tags: hyperref, counters, automation, labels, tabu

Is there any way to put an automatic label into the hyperref package's `\TextField` parameters field like this:

```
\newcounter{lexemeCounter}
\newcommand\lexemeCount{\stepcounter{lexeme}\lexemeCounterrabic{lexemeCounter}}

\newcommand{\formlabel}{\value{lexemeCounter}}

\TextField[name=\formlabel]{}
```

The reason I need to do this is because I have a table with about 1000 entries and I would like to add an editable comment column.

A minimal example would look like this (Although this is a minimal example, I purposely chose to use the `longtabu` environment, because that is the real-world scenario):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec} %I only use xelatex
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{lexemeCounter}
\newcommand\lexemeCount{\stepcounter{lexemeCounter}\arabic{lexemeCounter}}
\newcommand{\formlabel}{\value{lexemeCounter}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{|[1pt black] X[.10,l] | X[.20,l] || X[.20,l] | X|[1pt black]}
   Row & English & German & Comments\\
   \hline
   \lexemeCount & apple   & Apfel  & \TextField[name=\formlabel]{}\\
   \lexemeCount & mouse   & Maus   & \TextField[name=\formlabel]{}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

All of my attempts have failed. For some reason, the `name=\formlabel` stays literal (or does not increment) and therefore all edits are applied to each `\TextField`

Comment: What about macro? Something like `\def\TF{\expandafter\csname TextField\endcsname[name=\formlabel}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\formlabel` (i.e. `\value{lexemeCounter}}`) does not expand to something useful as a name for the `\TextField` command, so it's ignored and does show nothing.

Using `\number\value{lexemeCounter}` however works. The value must be explicitly changed to a literal number representation for a string label (i.e. a text field name)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %I only use xelatex
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{lexemeCounter}
\newcommand\lexemeCount{\stepcounter{lexemeCounter}\arabic{lexemeCounter}}%
\newcommand{\formlabel}{textfield::\number\value{lexemeCounter}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
  \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{|[1pt black] X[.10,l] | X[.20,l] || X[.20,l] | X|[1pt black]}
    Row & English & German & Comments\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \lexemeCount & apple   & Apfel  & \TextField[name=\formlabel]{} \tabularnewline
    \lexemeCount & mouse   & Maus   & \TextField[name=\formlabel]{}
  \end{longtabu}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer that is to the point! I forgot about this question. I have since found a new way to accomplish my goals, but this will come in handy again I am sure. (btw, I read your profile. There are no stupid questions as they all lead to understanding. (just stupid people haha)

Comment: @macmadness86: That profile text was a rant due to anger ;-) I will insert my original text in near future.