# Auto label inside a new command definition for easing the usage of hyperref

Tags: hyperref, labels, robust-commands

I am trying to build a controlled dictionary. I used a template where it's defined a command to insert a new entry. I would like to assign a label to each entry so that I can link similar terms with `hyperref` package. If I insert the label each time it works but it's quite a tedious task. I would like to insert the label with the same name of the entry, directly in the command as shown in my attempt below however it does not work. I studied this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119663/how-do-i-auto-label-hyperref-fillable-forms-textfield) but I could not find a solution to my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{ \scriptsize{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1}\ {(#2)}\ \textit{#3}\ $\bullet$\ {#4}}} 
%my atempt
\newcommand{\autoentry}[4]{\label{ter:{#1}}\scriptsize{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1}\ {(#2)}\ \textit{#3}\ $\bullet$\ {#4}}} 

\begin{document}
% expected behaviour but slow
\entry{myword}{myword}{ \label{ter:myword} masdfa asldkfj asld}{test}
% my attempt  
\autoentry{myword2}{myword2}{ masdfa asldkfj asld}{test}



\hyperref[ter:myword]{myword}
\hyperref[ter:myword2]{myword2}
\end{document}
```

The error that I've got is this one:

> You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you
>   have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside
>   \ref{...} is the same as what is written inside \label{...}.

Comment: Remove the braces in the label: `\label{ter:#1}`.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem, if you formalize this in an answer I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\label{ter:{#1}}` the inner braces are part of the label name. They are stored in aux-file:

```
\newlabel{ter:{myword2}}{{}{1}{}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

So either remove them in your definition

```
\label{ter:#1}
```

Or add the braces to the reference:

```
\hyperref[ter:{myword2}]{myword2}
```